# What is the 'balance' keyword in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix

```
contract Helper {
function getBalance() returns (uint bal) {
return this.balance; 
 }
}
```

Is this(balance) also a keyword in solidity? Where can I find their description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of Ether in this particular smart contract.

For example: If you deploy this smart contract and send it 5 Eth. Then this function will return "5".

Comment: Hi @AvocadoChocolate, Where can I find its  explanation?

Comment: here you go : https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/accounts/#an-account-examined

Answer (score 0):

it work like this:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity >0.8.0 <0.9.0;
contract aakash4dev{
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance; 
    }
}
```

it will give balance of the smart contract.